# Changing column data type recursively for all tables without affecting constraints

Tags: java, sql-server, internationalization, nvarchar

How to convert all **varchar** columns in schema to **nvarchar** effectively, without dropping constraints

I am using this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE VarCharToNvarChar
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE curChangeTypes CURSOR FOR
     SELECT column_name,
            table_name,
            character_maximum_length
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE DATA_TYPE='VARCHAR'
       AND table_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT table_Name
                          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                          WHERE DATA_TYPE='VARCHAR');

OPEN curChangeTypes;
DECLARE @cn VARCHAR(50),
        @tn VARCHAR(50),
        @cml INT;
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(8000);

FETCH NEXT FROM curChangeTypes INTO @cn,@tn,@cml;

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  IF(@cml = -1)
     SET @str = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tn + ' ALTER  COLUMN ' + @cn + ' NVARCHAR(MAX)';
  ELSE
     SET @str = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tn + ' ALTER  COLUMN ' + @cn + 
                ' NVARCHAR('+CAST(@cml AS VARCHAR)+')';

  EXEC(@str);
  FETCH NEXT FROM curChangeTypes INTO @cn,@tn,@cml;
END
CLOSE curChangeTypes;
DEALLOCATE curChangeTypes;
END
```

---

It fails due to constraints on fields

If we drop constraints procedure executed successfully

But constraints need to be intact

Suggest the best way to achieve the alter query [ varchar-->nvarchar ] without dropping constraints

Comment: You may have also CHECK,PRIMARY KEY,UNIQUE,FOREIGN KEY constraints and, also, you may have indexes on VARCHAR columns. You can't simply change data type of a column without affecting these objects.

Comment: If you think this will be so easy, just try using SSMS change column type where are constraint and click `Script` button to see how many underlying operation need to be done.

Comment: since MSSQL add a Default Constraint specifying null or empty string as well, so every column has atleast one constraint i.e. Default